# How to control subscribing to an exchange via stomp js?

Tags: rabbitmq, stompjs

I'm trying to connect to rabbitmq sever from the browser using the stompjs library. Right now every client can subscribe to any exchange. Is there a way to prevent a client from subscribing to a specific exchange?

Comment: @LutzHorn I skimmed that document but as far as I understand, I need to define a rabbitmq user for every client. Can rabbitmq handle many users, say 10 million?

Comment: That's a different question.

Comment: I would say yes RabbitMQ can definitely handle those many users.